# Not able to log lengthy messages using application insights trackEvent() method in Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure-application-insights

We are trying to log some lengthy message using AppInsights trackEvent() message. But it is not logging into AppInsights and not giving any error.

Please help me in logging lengthy string.

Please let us know the max limit for the trackEvent()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to log *messages* then you should be using the `trackTrace` methods of the AI SDK, not `trackEvent`.  `trackTrace` is intended for long messages and has a huge limit: (32k!)  See https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/develop/Schema/PublicSchema/MessageData.bond#L13

`trackEvent` is intended for named "events" like "opened file" or "clicked retry" or "canceled frobulating", where you might want to make charts, and track usage of a thing over time.

you can attach custom properties (string key, string value) and custom metrics (string key, double value) to anything.  and if you set the `operationId` field on things in the sdk, anything with the same `operationId` can be easily found together via queries or visualized in the Azure Portal or in Visual Studio:
[image: track operation]

Comment: Max len for TrackTrace is 10k.

Comment: says who/where?  I updated the link to the public schema for trace, and it literally has `[MaxStringLength("32768")]`

Comment: Try it yourself (as I did) or make a search. Plenty of docs out there saying 10000.

Comment: So 10000, not 10k as I wrote :-)

Comment: the link above is the source that the sdk itself uses to compile and validate and send data.  what *specific* documents are you finding on google indicate that 10k is the valid length, so I can get them corrected.  for other types *other than trace*, the name fields and property values are 8k. there shouldn't be anything "10k" anywhere.  what specific SDK are you using to verify this?

Comment: I'm just using AppInsights/telemetry in my app. and I also corrected it  from "10k" to "10.000" in the second comment.

Here is the first hit i get for "Azure tracktrace max len 10000"::
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.applicationinsights._telemetry_client.tracktrace

Comment: it is also 32k in the java sdk, here's the exact line that sets that: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Java/blob/bc4a4a486c889c4bdc7c16ec7c977aa190ede546/core/src/main/java/com/microsoft/applicationinsights/internal/schemav2/MessageData.java#L133  I'll get the team to update the docs on azure.

Comment: Not sure why there is this difference, but I still get an exception if the message is larger than 10000.

Comment: are you using a current version of the sdk?  if you're getting exceptions and shouldn't, report it as an issue on the java sdk GitHub, in the link above

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed limitation regarding the length. For example, the limit of the Name property of an event is 512 characters. See https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/master/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Extensibility/Implementation/Property.cs#L23

You can split it on substrings and put in Properties collection, each collection value length is 8 * 1024. I got this as a tip when I asked for it. See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/84bd5ade-0b21-47cc-9b39-c6c7a292d87e/dependencytelemetry-sql-command-gets-truncated?forum=ApplicationInsights. Never tried it myself though

Comment: Is the limit is applicable for Node js AppInsights also?

Comment: Yes. It is defined by the underlying storage of AI